# Powershell export csv foreach loop for inactive AD accounts

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, active-directory

Hi How do I export the following powershell foreach loop into CSV | export-csv filename.csv sadly doesnt work on foreach loops. Also the Manager paramenter outputs DN only, Is there a way to display the managers email or SamAccountName in the same output instead of DN?

```
$90Days = (get-date).adddays(-90)
$OUSearch = 

"OU=Contractors,OU=User,OU=x,OU=NZ,OU=Office,DC=add,DC=company,DC=coop,DC=us",
"OU=Contractors,OU=User,OU=xxx,OU=NZ,OU=Office,DC=add,DC=company,DC=coop,DC=us",
"OU=Contractors,OU=User,OU=xxxx,OU=NZ,OU=Office,DC=add,DC=company,DC=coop,DC=us",
"OU=Contractors,OU=User,OU=xxxxx,OU=NZ,OU=Office,DC=add,DC=company,DC=coop,DC=us",
"OU=Contractors,OU=User,OU=xxxxxx,OU=NZ,OU=Office,DC=add,DC=company,DC=coop,DC=us"

Foreach ($ou in $OUSearch){
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -filter {(lastlogondate -le $90days -or passwordlastset -le               $90days) -and (enabled -eq $True)} -Properties lastlogondate, passwordlastset, manager |    Select SamaccountName, Name, Email, Manager, lastlogondate, passwordlastset, Enabled

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways I know to do that.

Assign the result of the foreach loop to a variable and then export at the end:

```
$result =
 foreach ($SomeThing in $SomeThings)
  {
    #Create an object
  }

$result | Export-csv c:\somedir\somethings.csv
```

Or wrap the foreach loop in a sub-expression and then pipe directly to Export-csv:

```
$(foreach ($SomeThing in $SomeThings)
  {
    #Create an object
  }) | Export-csv c:\somedir\somethings.csv
```

You can also use a script block instead of the sub-expression:

```
&{foreach ($SomeThing in $SomeThings)
  {
    #Create an object
  }} | Export-csv c:\somedir\somethings.csv
```

Not recommended, but too often seen is to create an array and do repetitive additions to the array inside the loop.  Bad idea. Don't do this:

```
$result = @()

foreach ($SomeThing in $SomeThings)
  {
    #Create an object
    $result += $object
  }

 $result | Export-csv c:\somedir\somethings.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Having recently had trouble with a similar issue, I might try calling your filter as a string, rather than a codeblock. Something like:

```
ForEach ($ou in $OUSearch) {
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -filter '( lastlogondate -le $90days -or passwordlastset -le $90days ) -and ( enabled -eq $True )' -Properties lastlogondate, passwordlastset, manager | Select SamaccountName, Name, Email, Manager, lastlogondate, passwordlastset, Enabled 
} | export-csv test.csv
```

This, at least, seemed to work for me in similar straits.